# extjs3.4: How to access items in a panel that do not have id/itemId

Tags: javascript, extjs, dynamic, tree, extjs3

I just started using ExtJS 3.4 version. And I was not sure how to access the items within the panel when there is no id or itemId assigned to it. I have used Ext JS 4.2 before but I need to use 3.4 version for now.

In my case, I am using border layout here. I have a tree panel on the east region and a tabpanel in the center region. And I want to update the center region dynamically with grids or forms based on the tree node clicked.

here is my code for the tabpanel

```
{
                        xtype : 'tabpanel',
                        title : 'Center Panel',
                        width : 200,
                        region : 'center',
                        items:[gridpnl]
}
```

And here is the complete code that I tried
     
        First ExtJs Page
        
            
            
            
            
        
        
        
            Ext.onReady(function () {

```
        Ext.namespace('Class');
        Class.create = function() {
            return this.init(config);
            }
        };

        Ext.namespace('FirstOOPS');
        FirstOOPS = Class.create();
        FirstOOPS.prototype = {
         init: function (config) {

                var store= new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                fields: [{name: 'C1'},{ name: 'C3'}, {name: 'C5'}]
            });
            var myData= [['abcdC11','C3','C5'],['asdf','C3_asdf','C5_asdf']]
            store.loadData(myData);

            var gridpnl= new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                layout: 'fit',
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                store: store,
                columns:[
                       {header: "C1", dataIndex: 'C1'},
                       {header: "C3", dataIndex: 'C3'},
                       {header: "C5", dataIndex: 'C5' }
                       ]
            });

            var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            layout : 'border',
            items : [
    {
        region: 'east',
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'Navigation',
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        width: 200,
        autoScroll: true,
        split: true,
        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'Grid',
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: 'Form',
                leaf: true
            }]
        }),
        rootVisible: false,
        listeners: {
            click: function(n) {

                if(n.text=='Grid'){
                Ext.Msg.alert(n.text);

            }
             }
        }
    },{
                    xtype : 'tabpanel',
                    title : 'Center Panel',
                    width : 200,
                    region : 'center',
                    items:[gridpnl]

    }
    ]
    });
            new Ext.Viewport({
                layout : 'fit',
                items : [mainPanel]
            });   
        }
    };
    var firstObj = new FirstOOPS();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone tell me how to access this without id, so that I can update the tabpanel dynamically or create new tabs based on the tree node click.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to access tabpanel without using id or items id

```
this.up().items.items[1]
```

to test the above code I am alerting the title of the tab panel by following code

```
      alert(this.up().items.items[1].title);
```

it will alerts the title of the tab panel

Comment: Thanks..could you please tell me what does `this` refer to here..? I am putting the same alert message in treepanel listener..but I am getting error saying undefined not a function

Comment: this will refer to current object and this.up() will refer to parent object .. put this.up() in console.log and check in firefug